# How to use MongoID validates_inclusion_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, mongoid

I have a model with a field that can contain a list of values. I want that list to be limited to a subset. I want to use `validates_inclusion_of`, but probably misunderstand that validation.

```
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :foo,   :type => Array

  validates_inclusion_of :foo, in: %w[foo bar]
end

p = Profile.new
p.valid?   #=> false; this is correct, as it should fail on empty lists.
p.foo = ["bar"]
p.valid?   #=> false; this is incorrect. I would expect it to pass now.
p.errors   #=> {:foo=>["is not included in the list"]}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can `validates_inclusion_of` be used for arrays?

Comment: I would recommend writing a custom validator for this otherwise maintaining the permutations-combinations of inclusion list might get unmanageable over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your field value is an array (`field :foo,   :type => Array`)
Validation expects field to be not an array to check its inclusion.
By your example validation is checking for ['foo', 'bar'].include?(['bar']) # => false

So correct your :in option in validates_inclusion_of:

```
validates_inclusion_of :foo, in: [['foo'], ['bar']]
```